# Filter information in the database with React

Tags: reactjs, filter

I would like to filter information on different pages and I am having difficulty.

I have a first page with a customers list. I manage to display it with the map method. This is my code and it's working perfectly:

```
.map((customer) => {
      return (
        <TableRow hover role="checkbox" tabIndex={-1} key={customer.code}>
          <TableCell align="center">{customer.name}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center">{customer.description}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center">
            <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to={`/customer/${customer.uuid}`}>
              <Button>View</Button>
            </Link>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      );
```

but I block here: I would like to have a second page with a workshops list with the customer in question (not a list of all the workshops of the database). Here is my database: customers (uuid, name, description) and workshops (uuid, name, address, city, country, wsp_user_uuid).

This is my code for the second page for the moment :

```
const ViewCustomer = () => {
    const [workshops, setWorkshops] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const getWorkshops = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get("http://zzzz/workshop");
      setWorkshops(result.data);
    };
    getWorkshops();
  }, []);

const tableHeader = columns.map((column) => (
    <TableCell
      key={column.id}
      align={column.align}
      style={{ minWidth: column.minWidth }}
    >
      {column.label}
    </TableCell>
  ));

const mainContent = workshops
    .map((workshop) => {
      return (
        <TableRow hover role="checkbox" tabIndex={-1} key={workshop.code}>
          <TableCell align="center">{workshop.name}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center">{workshop.adress}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center">{workshop.city}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center">{workshop.country}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      );
    });



    return (
            <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>{tableHeader}</TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>{mainContent}</TableBody>
              </Table>
    );
};

export default ViewCustomer;
```

Do you have any advice or tips for me a filter to make this second page?

Comment: What part of doing that are you having trouble with? How to query the database? How to fetch that data? How to update the page?

Comment: I edit my post for more information. I'm looking to filter my second page. For the moment I have a list of all the workshops with the map method, but I am looking to apply a filter and only have all the workshops of a single customer

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to show only workshop data where `wsp_user_uuid` equal to selected customer. If so - 1st you should pass customerId into `ViewCustomer` component. Example: `const ViewCustomer = ({customerId}) => {...`

2nd. Use filter before rendering workshop data

```js
const mainContent = workshops
    .filter( w => w.wsp_user_uuid === customerId )
    .map((workshop) => {
```

And finally , usage of the component should look like `<ViewCustomer customerId={selectedCustomer.uuid} />`

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you! I would like the workshop's wsp_user_uuid to be equal to the customer's uuid. But I don't understand where i should place the component `<ViewCustomer customerId={selectedCustomer.uuid} />`

Comment: On the page, where you are using the component. As I see you using `uuid` as routing param - so you'll get it on the page  with something like `<Route path="/customer/:uuid" children=<ThePageYouLookingFor /> />` inside `ThePageYouLookingFor` you should be using something like `const {uuid} = useParams()` so you may use in render portion something like  `<ViewCustomer customerId={uuid} />`

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand why I need to make a component on the second one and where to place it. I have a first page page `"/customer"` with a customers list and a view button as the first code. When I click on it, I get to this second page `"/customer/: uuid"` with my second code where I map "/workshop" with get and axios. I thought I just needed a filter

Comment: Just use `const {uuid} = useParams()` in the second page, than  `const mainContent = workshops.filter( w => w.wsp_user_uuid === uuid ).map((workshop) => {`

Comment: Yes it's finally working, I find this solution too. Thank you so mush !